# Using __includes in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

The NetLogo dictionary says that one can include multiple files by writing `__includes [ filename ... ]`,

But when I write

```
__includes [ utils.nls ]
```

I get a compiler error message: `closing bracket expected`, with `utils.nls` highlighted. (The same thing happens if I leave off the `.nls` extension.)

What is the correct way to include multiple source files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The filename must be a string, thus:

```
__includes [ "utils.nls" ]
```

Or:

```
__includes [ "utils1.nls" "utils2.nls" ]
```

Comment: I agree that the documentation could have been clearer. I have proposed a small addition to it: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/pull/1562.